# JQuery table not coming when using extends tag

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am making a jquery data table and extending an admin panel. The issue is thatwhen I use the extend tag to extend the admin panel into the jquery data table page, the jquery table doesnt come

below is only JQuery table

[image: 1]

below is the image with the admin panel where the JQuery table doesnt come

[image: 2]

below is the html code for the JQuery table using extends tag

```
{% extends 'polls/base.html' %}
{% block content %}
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8"
    src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.4/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<table id="table_id">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Categories</th>
            <th>Sub-Categories</th>
            <th>Colors</th>
            <th>Size</th>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>SKU Number</th>
            <th>Product Details</th>
            <th>Quantity</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    {% for result in data %}
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><b>{{result.id}}</b></td>
            <td><b>{{result.categories}}</b></td>
            <td><b>{{result.sub_categories}}</b></td>
            <td><b>{{result.color}}</b></td>
            <td><b>{{result.size}}</b></td>
            <td><b>{{result.title}}</b></td>
            <td><b>{{result.price}}</b></td>
            <td><b>{{result.sku_number}}</b></td>
            <td><b>{{result.product_details}}</b></td>
            <td><b>{{result.quantity}}</b></td>
            <td>
                <a href="/update/{{result.id}}/">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary">
                        Edit
                    </button>
                </a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="/delete/{{result.id}}/" onclick="return confirm('Are You Sure you want to delete?')">
                    <button class="btn btn-danger">
                        Delete
                    </button>
                </a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>

<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#table_id").dataTable();
    });
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

Help is greatly appreciated thanks!

Comment: What's in `polls/base.html`? Clearly something inside of it breaks javascript code and causes an error if this happens when you add that. Have you checked the console?

Comment: yes now the problem got solved, I was  not having the same number of columns in thead and tr